# Error calculating the max while scanning a text file

Tags: java, file, input, java.util.scanner, java-io

I have just recently started learning Java and I am working on an exercise.

I am trying to read a text file and display the max, min, and average. So far I am able to output the average but have encountered an issue trying  find the  max. I planned on my min being my max+1 but I have seemed to have an issue with the max. The code is below and the error output below that. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Thank you!

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "scratch.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("The file: " + fileName + " has not been found, exiting program.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
    
        while (inputStream.hasNextInt()) {
            if (inputStream.nextInt() > max) {
                max = inputStream.nextInt();
            }
            sum = +inputStream.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        
        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println("The integer average is: " + sum / i);
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:945)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2267)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2221)
    at Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Comment: You reached the end of the file when a `nextInt` was expected. It's possible, because your `while` loop tests for `inputStream.hasNextInt()`. But, when that is `true`,  you can read 2 or 3 `inputStream.nextInt()` when only 1 is guaranteed.  So, fix your code to read `inputStream.nextIntt()` exactly one time within the `while` loop. And don't throw away results of such reads. Remember, successful `nextInt()` advances with each call.

Comment: Find related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+NoSuchElementException

Comment: In the future, you should resist the temptation to post until you've identified the problem via your own [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) efforts. Nine times out of ten, if you perform basic debugging to try to diagnose the problem, you're also going to discover the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Every call to `.nextInt()` consumes a token. You call it as many as 3 times in a single loop (if 'the next number' is higher than max, then get the number after THAT and store it in `max`, then get the number after *that* (so, 3 numbers total) and add it to sum. If the first number isn't higher, then just get the second number and add *that* to sum.

You want to call `.nextInt()` only once in that `while` loop. Assign the result of that to a variable and then do your `if` and add operations on that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're sorted out now with the comments about `nextInt`, but you might like to know you can make using the `Scanner`, together with collecting your stats, much easier by using streaming. Perhaps something to examine later on in your study:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;

public class Stats {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of("scratch.txt")))) {
            IntSummaryStatistics ss = s.tokens().
                mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).
                summaryStatistics();
                System.out.println(ss);
        }
    }
}
```